# CSS Selector getting crossed

Tags: html, css

I just have a simple button tag in HTML with a simple CSS Selector

and when I render the same 2 of my properties getting crossed out

[image]

there is no other selector applied on the button tag and I have also checked the parent tags no CSS selector is changing the color on parent tags as well. Could someone please help me if is there a way to identify why these 2 properties are getting crossed out?

```css
.call-button {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
  border: orange;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="call-button">My button</button>
```

Comment: don't filter by the class-name in the devtool, inspect the element to see **all** the CSS applied ti it

Comment: ^ the devtools is not showing you the default styles of button because you are filtering

Comment: I have tried without filter also

Comment: I have tried filter with "color" keyword as well

Comment: don't filter with anything, inspect the element and see all the styles

Comment: Yes sir, I have done without the filter also

Answer (score 1):

There is a chrome page specifically for this here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/overrides/

1. From the Elements panel, open the Computed pane.
2. Scroll through the list of properties and expand the one that you want to investigate further.
3. Click the blue link next to a declaration to jump to open the Sources panel and jump to that declaration's source code. See Make a minified file readable if the code is minified.